# Where do I start with rJava?

Tags: r, rjava

I am not a Java programmer. I program R and C++.  I have some java code that I want to include in an R package.  The basics of the program are this:

1. Read data from standard input.
2. Run a MCMC chain.
3. output to a file.

I want to convert this to R where I can run the program from R.  I am familiar with Rcpp package and am used to some of the conveniences of it.  Where do I start with the rJava package to learn to use this code.

Specifically i have the following questions.

1. How to I transfer data to java from R, e.g. numeric vector, factor, etc.
2. How do I run methods of a class?
3. How do I include java code in a package?

The rJava documentation is not very helpful.  Does anyone have a tutorial on this?

Comment: Hi Andrew -- the rJava page on CRAN list several dozen packages using it.  Maybe you can poke a stick at those to see how they do things?

Comment: @JDLong has a nice example of calculating sun radiation on Earth's surface. Maybe he can chip in and point you to the source code (maybe search "cmastication" on github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a "simple" way to do this and a somewhat harder way to do this. I'm a simple man so I lean toward the simple solution:

```
myCommand <- paste("/path/to/java", argument1, argument2, sep=" ")
system(shQuote(myCommand))
```

Then read in the output file using whatever R function makes sense.

The somewhat harder solution is to edit your Java code so it doesn't read from stdin, but gets passed a vector, or other Java object. I can't really generalize about how to alter your Java code, but if the Java function ultimately needs to be fed a vector, you'd do it something like this:

```
.jinit()
v <- .jnew("java/util/Vector")
rVector <- as.character(1:10)
addToV <- function( item ){
  v$add( item )
}
sapply(rVector, addToV)
```

I always find dealing with types in rJava to be a considerable pain, as you can see above.

One tip that will save you considerable time is this: When you have a Java object created in rJava you can figure out its methods by typing the name, a dollar sign, and then hit tab. So using the v object created above type "v$"  and you should get this:

```
1> v$
v$add(                 v$hashCode()           v$contains(            v$size()               v$elementAt(           v$capacity()           v$containsAll(         v$firstElement()       v$removeElement(       v$iterator()           v$wait()
v$get(                 v$clone()              v$isEmpty()            v$toArray()            v$remove(              v$ensureCapacity(      v$removeAll(           v$insertElementAt(     v$removeElementAt(     v$listIterator()       v$getClass()
v$equals(              v$indexOf(             v$lastIndexOf(         v$toArray(             v$elements()           v$trimToSize()         v$retainAll(           v$lastElement()        v$setElementAt(        v$listIterator(        v$notify()
v$toString()           v$clear()              v$addAll(              v$addElement(          v$set(                 v$subList(             v$copyInto(            v$removeAllElements()  v$setSize(             v$wait(                v$notifyAll()
1> v$
```

Good luck, and be sure and yell if you have specific snags.

Comment: Thanks, This should give me what I need to get things going.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the Deducer plug-in development document. While it is geared towards packages extending Deducer, some sections are general.

Running java methods in R:
http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development#wwjoir

Bringing R objects into java and creating a package with java code:
http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development#suaptijc

Full disclosure: Deducer is my project.

Comment: Since you have the link www.deducer.org in your profile, you should also mention in your answer that you are affiliated to the product(s)/solution(s) you propose.

Comment: Fair enough. I've add a disclosure statement.